# Can I tell emacs to paste (middle mouse button) on the cursor position?

Tags: emacs

If I paste text from, for example, the browser into emacs, the emacs cursor is often already at the position where I want to paste the text. If I would use emacs in console mode, I could just move the mouse over the text and press the middle button (if I had gpm disabled). But when using emacs in X (window) mode, I have to move the mouse cursor at the exact position where I want to past the text.

**Is there a way to tell emacs to use the current emacs cursor position for pasting, instead of the mouse cursor position?**

I hope you get my problem. :-)

Comment: Good question, I noticed I lacked this functionality in certain scenarios. But looking back I would say I prefer standard behavior in about half the cases. Would be nice to have both modes quickly accessible at all times.

Comment: I only wish I could upvote this more. I'm baffled by the fact that the default is to paste where the mouse is located!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try this setting:

```
(setq mouse-yank-at-point t)
```

Comment: Great, although this settings doesn't show up on M-x mouse-yank... auto-complete, it works when I put this in my .emacs :-)

Comment: That's because it's a variable, not a function. You could use M-x set-variable RET mouse-yank-at-point (and completion should work here)

Comment: This should be the default setting IMHO.

Comment: Extra clarity: use the *middle* mouse button to paste your text at point, otherwise, you'll reset the position of point and you'll still paste at the mouse's position.