# How do I make Emacs honor (setq mouse-yank-at-point t) when using isearch?

Tags: emacs, mouse-click

When using Emacs in a terminal, if I start a search (C-s) and then middle-click paste something, it goes into the search no matter where I click. This is what I want to happen in the GUI.

This answer works for everything *except* when I'm in a command like C-s: [Can I tell emacs to paste (middle mouse button) on the cursor position?](https://superuser.com/questions/330849/can-i-tell-emacs-to-paste-middle-mouse-button-on-the-cursor-position)

When in a command, that answer's solution pastes at wherever the point is instead of into the command buffer. Is there a straightforward way to force it to paste into the command buffer (when active) instead of the editing area?